# Как завернуть тег a в span wp menu?

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'            => '', 
        'container'       => 'nav', 
        'container_class' => 'menu', 
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => '', 
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu(),
        ) ); ?>


<li id="menu-item-243" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-243"><a href="#prices>Цены</a></li>
```

Как сделать что бы `Цены` был завернут в `span`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкретно в Вашей ситуации. Достаточно указать значения `'link_before'` и `'link_after'`

```php
<?php 
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'            => '', 
        'container'       => 'nav', 
        'container_class' => 'menu', 
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => '', 
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '<span>',
        'link_after'      => '</span>',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu(),
    ) ); 
?>
```

```html
<li id="menu-item-243" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-243"><a href="#prices><span>Цены</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть фильтр `nav_menu_item_title`

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_title',  __NAMESPACE__ . '\\filter_nav_menu_item_title', 10, 4 );

function filter_nav_menu_item_title( $title) {
    return "<span>$title</span> ";
}
```

Для работы с меню есть "семейство" хуков `nav_menu`, вот список:

- [nav_menu_css_class](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/nav_menu_css_class) - Позволяет изменять набор CSS классов у пункта меню.
- [nav_menu_item_args](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/nav_menu_item_args) - Позволяет изменить параметры (аргументы) отдельного элемента меню навигации (wp_nav_menu).
- [nav_menu_item_id](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/nav_menu_item_id) - Позволяет изменить атрибут ID элемента

  у пункта меню.

  [nav_menu_item_title](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/nav_menu_item_title) - Позволяет изменить заголовок пункта меню (анкор ссылки).

  [nav_menu_link_attributes](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/nav_menu_link_attributes) - Позволяет изменить HTML атрибуты  элемента меню: title, target, rel, href.

  [nav_menu_meta_box_object](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/nav_menu_meta_box_object) - Позволяет изменить объект, который используется для формирования метабокса в аккордеоне с выбором пунктов меню на странице создания меню в админке.

  [nav_menu_submenu_css_class](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/nav_menu_submenu_css_class) - Позволяет изменить CSS классы, добавленные к вложенным ul элементам (спискам меню). По умолчанию добавляется класс `sub-menu`.

  [pre_wp_nav_menu](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/pre_wp_nav_menu) - Позволяет изменить вывод функции `wp_nav_menu()` на раннем этапе, до работы основного кода функции.

  [walker_nav_menu_start_el](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/walker_nav_menu_start_el) - Позволяет изменить вывод начального элемента пункта меню.

  [wp_nav_menu](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_nav_menu) - Позволяет изменить HTML код меню навигации перед его выводом на экран.

  [wp_nav_menu_(menu_slug)_items](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_nav_menu_-menu_slug-_items) - Позволяет изменить уже сгенерированный HTML код пунктов у каждого меню в отдельности на основании его slug.

  [wp_nav_menu_args](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_nav_menu_args) - Позволяет изменить аргументы, передаваемые в функцию `wp_nav_menu()`, после того, как они были слиты с дефолтными значениями.

  [wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags) - Позволяет дополнить список HTML тегов, которые можно указать в параметре `container` при выводе меню функцией `wp_nav_menu()`. Фильтрует список тегов - контейнеров меню.

  [wp_nav_menu_items](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_nav_menu_items) - Позволяет изменить уже сгенерированный HTML код пунктов меню.

  [wp_nav_menu_objects](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_nav_menu_objects) - Позволяет изменить отсортированный список объектов пунктов меню, прежде чем на их основе будет сгенерирован HTML-код меню.